# Extract a pattern from a complex string

Tags: r, regex

How is it possible to extract the pattern S followed by a number from a string that looks like this?

e.g.    xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt

I would like only S1

Can anyone help me please?

Thank you a lot

Comment: Please provide some of the code that you have tried and explain where is your problem. This way we could address you a better solution.

Comment: `gsub(".*(S\\d).*","\\1","xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt")`

Comment: I dont see the reasons for the downvote. The question contains "example data" and "desired output" and is therefore very clear.

Comment: Would be great to have more example data and more context. @AndreElrico I didn't downvote but the question is missing any indication of research effort as well.

Comment: @mt1022 links missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `gsub`

```
string = "xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt"
gsub(".*_(S\\d+)_.*","\\1",string)
"S1"
```

Comment: `gsub(".*_(S\\d+)_.*","\\1","xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt")` would be better

Comment: Also `\\d+` might be useful

Answer (score 0):

can be done very easily

```
stringr::str_extract("xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt","(?<=_)S\\d+(?=_)")
```

Comment: Sticking to your logic but remaining within base R: `gsub(".*_(S\\d+)_.*", "\\1", "xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX_C-_x.txt")`

Answer (score 0):

With `stringr` package:

```
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all( "xxxx_x_S1_XXXXX'_C-_x.txt","([:upper:])(\\d)"))
[1] "S1"
```